# Get file from android package internal storage

Tags: java, android

So for test purposes I have an update function which checks the version of the up on my phone with the one that I have uploaded somewhere. Every works fine but when it goes to instal it just crashes and gives me this error.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.XXXX.demoapp/update/demo.apk

And here is where it crashes:

```
private static final String APK_SAVE_PATH  = "/data/data/com.example.XXXX.demoapp/update";

final File apk = new File(APK_SAVE_PATH,"demo.apk");


if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                    Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", apk);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
                                    intent.setData(apkUri);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                                    context.startActivity(intent);
                                } else {
                                    Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(apk);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                    intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    context.startActivity(intent);
                                }



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="apk" path="/data/data/com.example.XXXX.demoapp/update/" />
</paths>
```

Comment: For future reference, you should post code as a [mcve]. This means that the code you post should compile; it should have a class and method, just like any Java code. Also, it should be minimal; it should contain only just enough code to reproduce the error. For example, there is no reason for the `if` statement which checks the SDK version. Only show the code for the specific version you are asking about.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'll keep that in mind, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <files-path
        name="apk"
        path="/" />
</paths>
```

Apparently that does the trick